# Parsing string in multiline data with positive lookbehind

Tags: perl, parsing, multiline

I am trying to parse data like:

```
header1
-------
var1 0
var2 5
var3 9
var6 1

header2
-------
var1 -3
var3 5
var5 0
```

Now I want to get e.g. var3 for header2. Whats the best way to do this?

So far I was parsing my files line-by-line via

```
open(FILE,"< $file");
while (my $line = <FILE>){
    # do stuff
}
```

but I guess it's not possible to handle multiline parsing properly.

Now I am thinking to parse the file at once but wasn't successful so far...

```
my @Input;
open(FILE,"< $file");
while (<FILE>){ @Input = <FILE>; }
if (@Input =~ /header2/){ 
    #...
}
```

Comment: “*but I guess it's not possible to handle multiline parsing properly*” – if you were to show more of your actual code, maybe that problem could be solved? There is probably a simple solution without having to use complicated regexes. “*Now I am thinking to parse the file at once but wasn't successful so far...*” – Can you clarify how this doesn't work for you? There are a number of problems in that snippet, but they are all unrelated to the problem in your title (regexes with lookbehind). See also https://perlmaven.com/slurp for valuable pointers.

Answer (score 3):

The easier way to handle this is "paragraph mode".

```
local $/ = "";
while (<>) {
    my ($header, $body) =~ /^([^\n]*)\n-+\n(.*)/s
       or die("Bad data");

    my @data = map [ split ], split /\n/, $body;

    # ... Do something with $header and @data ...
}
```

The same can be achieved without messing with `$/` as follows:

```
my @buf;
while (1) {
    my $line = <>;
    $line =~ s/\s+\z// if !defined($line);
    if (!length($line)) {
       if (@buf) {
          my $header = shift(@buf);
          shift(@buf);
          my @data = map [ split ], splice(@buf);

          # ... Do something with $header and @data ...
       }

       last if !defined($line);
       next;
    }

    push @buf, $line;
}
```

(In fact, the second snippet includes a couple of small improvements over the first.)

Quick comments on your attempt:

- The `while` loop is useless because `@Input = <FILE>` places the remaining lines of the file in `@Input`.
- `@Input =~ /header2/` matches `header2` against the stringification of the array, which is the stringification of the number of elements in `@Input`. If you want to check of an element of `@Input` contains `header2`, will you will need to loop over the elements of `@Inputs` and check them individually.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> while (<FILE>){ @Input = <FILE>; }
> ```

This doesn't make much sense. "While you can read a record from FILE, read all of the data on FILE into `@Input`". I think what you actually want is just:

```
my @Input = <FILE>;
```

> ```
> if (@Input =~ /header2/){
> ```

This is quite strange too. The binding operator (`=~`) expects scalar operands, so it evaluates both operands in scalar context. That means `@Input` will be evaluated as the number of elements in `@Input`. That's an integer and will never match "header2".

A couple of approaches. Firstly a regex approach.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $file = 'file';

open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;

my $data = join '', <$fh>;

if ($data =~ /header2.+var3 (.+?)\n/s) {
  say $1;
} else {
  say 'Not found';
}
```

The key to this is the `/s` on the `m//` operator. Without it, the two dots in the regex won't match newlines.

The other approach is more of a line by line parser.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $file = 'file';

open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;

my $section = '';

while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  # if the line all word characters,
  # then we've got a section header.
  if ($_ !~ /\W/) {
    $section = $_;
    next;
  }

  my ($key, $val) = split;
  if ($section eq 'header2' and $key eq 'var3') {
    say $val;
    last;
  }
}
```

We read the file a line at a time and make a note of the section headers. For data lines, we split on whitespace and check to see if we're in the right section and have the right key.

In both cases, I've switched to using a more standard approach (lexical filehandles, 3-arg `open()`, `or die $!`) for opening the file.

Comment: I also tried that regex approach with `/s` before but thought the `.` would match "as much as possible" between the two keywords. If I would search for header1 - var2, then it would match header2 - var2 again? Or isn't this the case?

Comment: You're right. It only works by accident - because `header2` is the last header in your file. My second solution still works though.